# Android Simple way for User Color Selections

Tags: android

How can you change application colors on the fly?

I am currently using the following to change the background:
LinearLayout mScreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);  mScreen.setBackgroundColor( mycolor );

I tried to use Style's to change the text using:

    @color/white

The problem is that Spinners/Buttons and Spinner-Popup-Lists all change to white text as well, making them unreadable.  I have over 20 Classes in my app that all need to be able to change color combination's.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create several [themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). To apply a theme at runtime, call [`setTheme`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme(int)) in your activities' `onCreate` methods (before `setContentView`). You can force re-creation and thus re-theming of your activity by doing something like:

```
startActivity(getIntent());
finish();
```

Comment: That is what I did using a Style.  The problem is that when text is set to white, "<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>"  all the text on the screen turns white, including popup spinners - white text on white background.